# jQuery j scrollpane auto mouse moving scroll

Tags: jquery, mouse, scrollpane

I'm using jquery Jscrollpane. on my page there are different scrolling sections.
all sections with scrolling are working fine, but there is a div that is working also fine, but problem is only without mousescroll div is scrolling with the position of mouse cursor even my cursor is out of that div, that is something weird.This is the syntax

```
SearchScroll=$('.SearchResultScroller');
SearchMaxHeight=SearchScroll.height(); 

if(SearchMaxHeight >=200 ){
    SearchScroll.css('height',200);    
    $('.SearchResultScroller').jScrollPane();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I use jscrollpane for most of the websites I build but never come across such thing... but I have had numerous weird problems and solution to most of them was updating the plugin/downloading a fresh copy and was sorted out...

One other thing I could think of maybe conflicting with some of your other scripts...
I've had that problem also :(

Comment: Each section has different ID, i dont think there is conflicting issue. let me try with other freash copy of that plugin.

Comment: Well if you have better answer then why don't you do it! Just trying help, doesn't really matters if you reply as answer or comment! In fact what I suggested could resolve the problem! Such a haters :(